# Create subpartitioning in MySQL

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I want to create a partitioning and subpartitioning on my MySQL table in order to optimize the performance of the table.

For Ex :-

```
Create table mytest (id int not null, mydate date)
PARTITION BY LIST (id)
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(mydate))
(
PARTITION P01 VALUES IN (1,2,5,6,8,10)
(
SUBPARTITION S01 VALUES LESS THAN ('2011-10-23'),
SUBPARTITION S02 VALUES LESS THAN ('2011-10-16'),
SUBPARTITION S03 VALUES LESS THAN ('2011-10-09')
));
```

like this i m trying to create the subpartitioning but getting an error which says incorrect syntax near RANGE.

Can anyone help me with the info whether PARTITION BY LIST AND SUBPARTITION BY RANGE is allowed.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot subpartition by `RANGE`.  You can only subpartition by `HASH` or `KEY`.  It is stated in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-subpartitions.html):

`"In MySQL 5.1, it is possible to subpartition tables that are partitioned by RANGE or LIST. Subpartitions may use either HASH or KEY partitioning."`

Comment: mysql 5.7 as well > `"Issues with subpartitions. Subpartitions must use HASH or KEY partitioning. Only RANGE and LIST partitions may be subpartitioned; HASH and KEY partitions cannot be subpartitioned."`